# multiple checkboxes and mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

how can I make a query based on multiple checkboxes with using ajax.(For exapmle for e-shop )

Checkboxes

```
        <div id="checkboxes">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="Zara" >zara</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="Nike" >nike</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="Adidas" >Adidas</label>
        </div>


        <div id="color">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="red" >red</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="black" >black</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="blue" >blue</label> 
         </div>

        <div id="style">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="classic" >classic</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="modern" >modern</label>              
        </div>
```

Query

```
 $brand = $_POST['brand'];
 $color = $_POST['color'];
 $style = $_POST['style'];


$Query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE brand IN ('" . implode("','", $brand) . "') AND color IN ('" . implode("','", $color) . "') AND style IN ('" . implode("','", $style) . "')";
$QueryResult = mysqli_query($connection , $Query);


while($QueryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)){
?>
<div><p><?php echo $QueryRow['cost'];?></p></div>
<div><img src="<?php echo $QueryRow['img']; ?>"></div>
<?php
}
}
    ?>
```

Also , I have js script for passing array with values taken from checkboxes, but it doesn't related to problem, that is why I do not post script.

Problem:

How to avoid error if on of checkboxes have not been checked?
(For example I've chosen only red color => then I should get all results related to red color, but it gives error if I did not choose at least one checkbox from every group ).

Any ideas?

Comment: Check if your `POST` variables are set first using `isset()`, otherwise, modify the query with conditionals or assign the variables to empty strings

Comment: It is not good way, because I have many groups And if I use your solution , then I should consider or possible ways for checked groups....It will be a lot of code

Comment: First of all, the parameters you are sending from the browser need to be sanitised. For that, you should be using at least PDO with parameter binding.
Second of all, what is the data that will be returned from a group without any selection? will it be an empty array? or will it be null?

Comment: I am not professional, that is why , I ask help in writing at least a pice of code

Comment: can you help me with writting code?